# Boostrap : Better way of lining up elements in columns and rows when you have to skip some

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am wondering if there is a better way of lining up elements using Bootstrap

Currently I have:

```
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-3 font-weight-bold">
                        Item Name
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3 font-weight-bold">
                        # of Item
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3 font-weight-bold">
                        Total
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-3 font-weight-bold">
                        Total Cost
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3 font-weight-bold">
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3 font-weight-bold">
                        ${this.state.total.toLocaleString()}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

For my second `row` elements, I put a `div` tag of `col-3 font-weight-bold` of nothing. Just so that My `Total Cost` and `${this.state.total.toLocaleString()}` will line up with `Item Name` and `Total`.

This is my personal project but I don't think that habit like this will pass the code review in real world. So is there a better way of lining up the columns when you need to skip certain columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offset-classes).

In your second row, eliminate the empty `div` and add offset to the last column:

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-3 font-weight-bold">
    Total Cost
  </div>
  <div className="col-3 offset-3 font-weight-bold">
    ${this.state.total.toLocaleString()}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just reading about the grid system and saw it too.!

Comment: Css grid is a good alternative (for browsers after IE11) https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid